# What is the difference between -ita and -ata?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

I've seen phrases translated using both forms and apparently meaning the exact same thing.

For example, I have seen "I am busy" translated as both *mi estas okupita* and *mi estas okupata.*

How do I know when to use *-ita* instead of *-ata*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*-ita* means that something **has had** something done to it, while *-ata* means something **is having** something done to it.

For example, if I call someone *mia amata filo*, that means that he is my son whom I love, I love him now. If I call him *mia amita filo*, that means he is my son whom I loved, but I don't necessarily still love him now - significantly different meaning. And *mia amota filo* is my son whom I don't necessarily love now, but will in the future - a rather odd and seldom used meaning.

In the case of *okupita* vs. *okupata*, the difference is mostly one of nuance, and the specific sense of *okupi*. If you say *mi estas okupita*, that emphasizes that something has, as it were, taken over you, taken over your attention, your time, your energy, etc. If you say *mi estas okupata*, that emphasizes that something is currently occupying your attention, time, etc. So in this case the meaning is very similar, and the difference is a matter of nuance and emphasis, but in most cases, *-ita* and *-ata* are significantly different.

If the main verb or the context is in the past tense, *-ita* indicates something that was completed at that time, while *-ata* indicates something that was ongoing at the time.

Comment: That's a great explanation @kristan, thanks!